# Append form data object?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im sending an image to the server using form data.

```
//create form data from form
var formData = new FormData($('#my-form')[0]);

//append the image
formData.append('file', myFile);

//add data from crop plugin
formData.append('file-data', cropData);

//POST
$.ajax({
        url: /upload,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData
    })
```

My issue occurs when I try and add the data from the crop plug in, it logs ok:

```
Object {x: 140, y: 273.49999999999994, width: 520, height: 520, rotate: 0}
```

but once posted in PHP it just dumps as an empty array with no properties.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var temp = Object {x: 140, y: 273.49999999999994, width: 520, height: 520, rotate: 0}

JSON.stringify(temp) 
// that will be ok looks in php in json_decode($_POST['data'])   

$.ajax({
  url: '/upload',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  data: JSON.stringify(temp)
})
```

and in php:

```
$data = json_decode( $_POST['data'] ) ;
```

Thats the answer - you have to convert object/hash from js to json before send to php.

Comment: `formData` is not a basic object. You can't stringify it to JSON.

Comment: I did. `var formData = new FormData` is quite relevant.

Comment: @Quentin OP write, that he console.log Object, so he just have to JSON.stringify that data before ajax.send

Comment: Even if we ignore the problem with your code not using `FormData` like the question - it won't work anyway. If you are going to pass a JSON string directly to `data: ` in jQuery ajax, then you need to specify the content type of the request as `application/json` and read the data from STDIN instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: what are u talking about? in php $temp =  json_decode( $_POST['data'] ) ; echo $temp['x'] gives u 140. where i made mistake?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Your code is sending a JSON encoded request, not a Form Encoded request with JSON embedded in the `data` property.

Comment: i dont sure about php, but in rails it enough - dataType: 'json',

Comment: PHP has no built in functionality for parsing JSON requests. You have to do it manually.

Comment: what u mean manually? i use in php json_encode($var); and it worked ok, what version of php did u mean? i going to write test files right now, wait for it

Comment: I mean you have to read the raw data of the body of the HTTP request and pass it through `json_decode`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74631/discussion-between-legendary-and-quentin).

Comment: @Quentin i test it, - you were right, my appologies

Comment: This is a good answer, I was able to modify it and apply it to my problem and it worked. I just stringifyied my var in form data then json decoded it the other end.

Comment: @panthro glad to hear it!

Comment: @Legendary your username lives up to your coding skills - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass an plain object as the second argument to `append` on a `FormData` object. (Well, you can, but it will be stringified, which will usually give you `"[object Object]"`).

You need to add each piece of data separately. You can use PHP's naming conventions to get an array at the other end.

```
for (var prop in cropData) {
    if (cropData.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        formData.append('file-data[' + prop + ']', cropData[prop]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Quentin this is a great solution, but I found the other answer easier to implement. Thanks anyway!